# JPA map non-id field as foreign key

Tags: java, jpa

I have two entities as follows:

```
@Entity  
public class Entity1  
{
  @Id  
  Long id;  
  @Basic  
  @OneToOne  
  @Column(unique=true,nullable=false)  
  String awesome;  
...    
}  



and

@Entity  
public class Entity2  
{  
  @Id  
  Long id;  
  @OneToOne(mappedBy="awesome",targetEntity=Entity1.class)    
  @Column(name="myAwesome", insertable=false,updateable=false)   
  @Basic   
  String awesome;  //FK to Entity1  
}
```

I am expecting SQL to be generated that looks like this:

```
Alter Table Entity1 Add Constraint Entity1Entity2_Awesome Foreign Key (myAwesome) References Entity1.Awesome
```

Currently no SQL is being generated, I am using eclipselink.

Answer (score 1):

A String cannot be a OneToOne, and you can't mark something as a Basic and a OneToOne.

To create a OneToOne relationship use,

@OneToOne
Entity2 entity2;

All relationships should be by Id, not by a non-id field such as awesome.  It is possible to define a foreign key on a non-Id field in EclipseLink, but not in JPA, you would need to use a DescriptorCustomizer for this.

In general relationships should be by Id, so either reconsider the relationship of the Id.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [@JoinColumn](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/persistence/javadoc-1_0-fr/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html) here and explicitly specify names of column for join.